# Why can't I nest the ADDRESS() formula inside the ROW() formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=ADDRESS(3,1)  'evaluates to $A$3

=ROW($A$3)     'evaluates to 3
```

Why can't I nest them?

```
=ROW(ADDRESS(3,1)) 'Gives an error.
```

Comment: May I ask what you are using this for. What is your goal.

Comment: One thing to be aware of: INDIRECT and ADDRESS are volatile which means they recalculate every time Excel has a change done.  This can slow performance drastically if too many are used.  I have found little use for INDIRECT and ADDRESS and can usually replace them with non volatile options

Comment: **ROW()** finds the row number but you already know the row number when you use **ADDRESS()** so not sure why you would like to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite interesting. So the `Address()` function outputs the range as string? And that's why we use `Indirect()` which converts string reference to actual range?

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that one!

Comment: Do two volatiles cancel out like a double negative in English? 8)

Answer (score 2):

instead of using ADDRESS which returns a string, consider using INDEX which will return a cell reference.  The general format of INDEX is:

```
INDEX(Range you want to look in, rows down from top row, columns right for first column)
```

so in order to reference your whole sheet like address would you would need to select the range of the entire sheet:

```
  =INDEX($A$1:$XFD$1048576,3,1)
```

The above formula actually returns the cell reference of $A$3 ($ is due to 3 and 1 being hard coded) then turns around and displays the contents of $A$3.  As a result you don't actually see the $A$3.  On the interesting side of things it also means you can define a range with INDEX(...):INDEX(...).  To finish off your formula you would nest the INDEX in your ROW function as follows:

```
=ROW(INDEX($A$1:$XFD$1048576,3,1))
```

This avoids the use of the volatile function of INDIRECT and some of its other restrictions.

[image: POC]